# Why is this integer argument giving me a pointerEvent object in JS?

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, addeventlistener

im passing an integer to this callback for an EventListener and it messes up the argument for some reason

Function Definition:

```
const deleteTask = function (i) {               
    let temp = [];
    alert (i);  // shows "[object PointerEvent]" for some reason
    tasks.forEach((t) => {
        if (t.Id != i)
            temp.push(t);
    });

    tasks = [... temp];
    showTasks();
```

Function call:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) 
        document.getElementById(`deleteTask${tasks[i].Id}`).addEventListener("click", deleteTask, tasks[i].Id);
```

it has got nothing to do with the objects or array or anything like that, I think the problem may be specific to event listeners or callbacks.

There is no error message, it's just that the argument isn't passing as i expect it to.

Why is it behaving like this, and how can I get the behaviour I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) has three signatures- none of which are what you think exists:

```js
addEventListener(type, listener)
addEventListener(type, listener, options)
addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)
```

See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for what `options` and `useCapture` are.

The listener function is called when the event it listens to is triggered, and it will be passed the even object carrying the details of that event. For the `click` event, that's an instance of a [`PointerEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent).

Things are working exactly as they are supposed to work- but not how you thought they'd work because you understood wrong. I'm not saying this to put you down. It's just a fact.

If you want `tasks[i].Id` to be available to the callback, you can do this:

```js
document.getElementById(`deleteTask${tasks[i].Id}`)
  .addEventListener("click", (ev) => { deleteTask(tasks[i].Id); });
```

I replaced the callback with an arrow function that captures both the callback and what you want to pass to it, and calls the callback with what you want to pass to it.

Comment: thanks, ill definitely check that out in a bit, but how will i be able to remove the event listener then

Comment: @abijanu_101 that's a completely different question. You need to keep a reference to it and call [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: okay 'once' gives me the functionality i want, thanks for the help <3